# How do I define a 'no remap' alias?

Tags: shell, alias, zsh

Here's an example of the kind of alias definition I'm after:

Say I'm an ag user, and I want `ag` to pay attention to my `.ignore` file by default. So I add this to my `.zshrc`:

```
alias ag='ag --path-to-ignore ~/.ignore'
```

**But** I also want a second command, that acts like vanilla ag, for the rare occasions where I do want to search every single file. So I try to do this:

```
alias agnodotignore='ag'
```

It doesn't work, all this does is alias `agnodotignore` to `ag --path-to-ignore ~/.ignore`.

How can I write a 'no remap' alias definition that ignores my previous alias definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `\` is an escape for aliases to get to the actual, un-aliased command.

```
alias agnodotignore='\ag'
```

will give you the default `ag` output, i.e., not the aliased version

you could also just type `\ag` from the command line for the same effect.